Maven project src folder isn't created
My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1, and JDK is 21.0.3, maven is 3.9.8.
And I created my first maven project, but the src folder doesn't exist in the project, and the pom.xml is empty. (I have tried many times)
src folder doesn't exist
Many tries
My settings are:

page 4
page5, I don't know if this setting is right
After a few times I tried but it didn't turn out well, I change my settings as default.
default setting
page 4 and page 5 didn't change. But it still didn't turn out well.
I don't know what to do now, please give me some help. Thank you!
I've also set my maven path.

I try to fix my problem and I expect some can solve this problem.

First I recommend to use a more recent version of IntelliJ but that's not the problem here... What about simply creating the directories needed?

Did you create the project as a maven project or add the support after creating some other project?

Since there's nothing in there why not delete and start again?

How did you create the project? Did you use a template within IntelliJ? If so, which? Or did you use a Maven archetype? If so, which?

Update to the latest IntelliJ. Java 21 arrived a couple years after your version of IntelliJ. Tip: Delete every bit of your manual installation of IntelliJ. Then install JetBrains Toolbox App to automatically locate, download, install, and uninstall versions of IntelliJ.

Follow the tutorial and video for creating a Maven-driven project for Java in IntelliJ, by the excellent technical writer Trisha Gee.
